# Derivative of an integral function - chain rule

Tags: calculus, derivatives, definite-integrals, economics, chain-rule

I have this problem in one of my econ classes, and google is not helping much in finding satisfying answers.

So, lets say I have to write the first derivative of $f(x) = \Big[\int_0^1 x^{\frac{n-1}{n}}\Big]^{\frac{n}{n-1}}$. So the function is the integral (from 0 to 1) of $x$ in the power of $(n-1)/n$, then the entire integral function in the power of $n/(n-1)$.

I know we have to do a chain rule in order to derive the F.O.C and apply the $f(g(x))$, however, my question is the following:
In the course notes $f(u)$ is assumed to be $f(u)=u^{\frac{n}{n-1}}$, whereas the $g(x)$ is assumed to be $x^{\frac{n-1}{n}}$. Theus they differentiate the expression inside the integral.
When I derived on my own without following the course notes step by step, I assumed $g(x)$ to be the entire integral function so that the derivative of $g(x)$ just gave me the expression inside the integral unchanged.

I have had quite a few exchanges by email with my professor regarding this, but his answers never provide a direct response of why $g(x)$ is assumed to be the expression inside the integral and not vice-versa.

I hope my question is clear and hope you guys can give me an answer as my exam is approaching and I still do not understand the reason for this.

Comment: So you want the derivative of $\large{\left[\int_0^1 x^{\frac{n-1}{n}} \, dx\right]^{\frac{n-1}{n}}} ?$ If yes, which is the variable you want to differentiate after?

Comment: If you are taking a definite integral, then $f$ is not a function of $x$ as the integrand is a real number.

Comment: Hello :)  

I want to differentiate after x. But I am not sure how to apply the chain rule f(g(x)), especially the g(x) part. Is the g(x) only the expression inside the integral notation, or do I include the integral notation in g(x) ? And why? 

I really want to understand before exams and homework come my way haha :) 

Thank  youuu

Comment: Sorry, I just realized I had forgotten dx in the above expression

Comment: Did you pay attention to what @c_gnar wrote? Your function is a *constant* function (the value $f(x)$ depends only on $n$, not on $x$), so the derivative is simply $f'(x)=0$. Are you sure you've really written what you intended? (The forgotten $dx$ is not the issue here.)

Comment: Well, tbh I understand what c_gnar wrote. However, in my lecture notes the function is derived through a chain rule... And my problem is that even if I accept the derivative as being =/= 0, I honestly still am not sure about how the prof has applied the chain rule. 

And after going back and forth with my Econ professor by email a couple of times, I still have not received an answer that makes sense or that I understand at least... 

This was my last hope before having to mindlessly apply the same derivation method my prof has given us...

Comment: Again: Which is the variable you want to differentiate after?